# How to test a Ruby on Rails REST API using Chrome's extension Advanced Rest Client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, google-chrome

I was able to install the Chrome extension for this and to use it in a certain way as described in other questions answered here. For example when I am using the URL for the fully developed application.

However my problem is a little bit different. I am using basic authentication but not based on user id and password. I am using the email for user id and an authentication token instead of password.

Here is my curl command working very well at the console prompt and retrieving all users my application has:

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H 'Authorization: Token token="mytoken", email="levi.l.damian@gmail.com"' http://instrumon.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users/
```

This command connects as an admin and retrieves the list of users registered for my app.
Also my URL contains a distinct "api/v1" string.
Don't know how to replace in the "Construct" the password with the authentication token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the GET I used "Form" and under "Add new header" I typed Authorization and in the Value instead of using "Construct" I put a string like this:

Token token="mytoken", email="levi.l.damian@gmail.com"

And I used the URL like this:
https://instrumon.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users

The Response was a JSON containing the 6 user records I expected.